# How to like/follow on Instagram without using their API

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Recently Instagram changed their API's policy, which means you can no longer like/follow/unfollow using their API unless you are approved by Instagram to do so.

I own the website http://instapromobiz.com which uses JavaScript and PhP to automate likes/follows/unfollows using Instagram's API. This was doing great until Instagram made this update and I can no longer perform these actions.

My question is, is there any way to perform these actions without using Instagram's API? Sites like http://instagress.com are still working so there must be another way to perform these actions without using their API.

Does anybody have any suggestions that might point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems somewhat of a gray area...

Comment: "you can no longer like/follow/unfollow using their API unless you are approved by Instagram to do so." - Why not get their approval to continue using this feature?

Comment: My website automatically likes/follows users, this is against their terms and they will not approve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should submit your app for review. They usually answer quickly.

Go to Manage Clients (https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/), then click on Edit button of your App. Your submission can be made over Permissions tab.

But, unfortunatelly, it's probably Instagram won't authorize an app that do like/ follow automatically. They want to ensure an authentic and consistent experience for the Instagram Community, so those actions should be manual. Good luck.